# 2 channel per circuit component election

Tags: integrated-circuit, component-selection, buying

I was looking for some references for a level shifter connected to an intel edison and a found that they used a  [74LVC(H)1T45](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74LVC_LVCH1T45.pdf) which have one channel per circuit. Then I found the same IC but with two channel per circuit ([74LVC(H)2T45](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74LVC_LVCH2T45.pdf)) and it have the same price. Considering that they use the same IC seven times (see [link](http://download.intel.com/support/edison/sb/edison_arduino_hvm_8_26.pdf)), Which criteria should I use for choosing the components? Is there an advantage of using one channel per circuit instead of two?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the 74LVC2T45 is that the DIR pin would affect both channels. So you get into trouble if you have two IO-pins connected to the buffer, and need one pin to be input and the other one to be output, at the same time.

If that is not a problem, you could save some board space by using the dual channel buffer.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for using multiple single devices rather than a single multi-channel device could be routing or part placement on the PC board.

If you need one of these devices in a signal on the left of the PC board, and another on a signal on the right, it would probably be easier to use two single-channel devices located as convenient, rather routing both signals to a two-channel device.